# HTTPS_PROXY vs https_proxy

Tags: linux, http-proxy

as I know, Linux is case-sensitive.
and I usually export the http proxy like the below:

`export http_proxy= proxy:port
export https_proxy= proxy:port`

so I think that if I wrote like the below, it would work.

`export HTTP_PROXY= proxy:port
export HTTPS_PROXY= proxy:port`

but, it also works, and I want to know the reason, and why this works.

and I find a description at here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

> The environment variables can be specified in lower case or upper
>   case. The lower case version has precedence. http_proxy is an
>   exception as it is only available in lower case.

does this convention can applied everywhere?

ref:

1. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html
2. http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/unix8.html
3. http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html
4. http://sc.tamu.edu/help/general/unix/vars.html

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212894/whats-the-right-format-for-the-http-proxy-environment-variable-caps-or-no-ca

Answer (score 3):

actually I can not get the exact answer.
but after I investigation, I think the only reason is that,
all the applications which need internet connection that will try to find the  both
1. `https_proxy`
2. `HTTPS_PROXY`.
if one of them beed set up, it will use that to connect the internet.

Answer (score 1):

In general, environment variables are written in uppercase. `http_proxy` is exception sometimes. For instance, variable `HTTP_PROXY` can be controlled by attackers in CGI environments, as in [golang/go#16405](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16405):

> - The CGI spec defines that incoming request header "Foo: Bar" maps to environment variable `HTTP_FOO == "Bar"`. (see RFC 3875 4.1.18)
> - The `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable is conventionally used to configure the HTTP proxy for HTTP clients (and is respected by default for Go's net/http.Client and Transport)

So it really depends on a program (of course they may uses proxy settings in rc or config file):

- `curl` uses `http_proxy`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, `NO_PROXY` ([reference](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html))
- `wget` uses `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, `no_proxy`  ([reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Proxies.html))

You may set up environment variable in both cases to be sure, for example:

```sh
export http_proxy=http://proxy.my.com:8080
export https_proxy=http://proxy.my.com:8080
export no_proxy=.host1,.my.com,.local
# reuse values for another case
export HTTP_PROXY=${http_proxy}
export HTTPS_PROXY=${https_proxy}
export NO_PROXY=${no_proxy}
```

There is a similar topic https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212894/whats-the-right-format-for-the-http-proxy-environment-variable-caps-or-no-ca